# Bower not work Could not find the End of Central Directory Record

Tags: javascript, node.js, bower

I have problems with bower today morning.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOA29.png

Yesterday all works good. Can't find reason of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is bower bug on version 1.7.1 downgraded to 1.7.0 and all works good.

Here link to issue. https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/2101